# How to return the position of word in the line, C language

Tags: c, algorithm

I have some problems with finding the position of the word in the text file.
The problem is when user enters a word to search, the program have to show line number and position in this line. My code is only shows line number but how I can add the position of word at this line?

P.S.I think I have used not efficient way in searching function...

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int Search_in_File(char *str);
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    char word;

    printf("Please enter a word to search:\n");
    scanf("%s", &word);
    Search_in_File(&word);
}
int Search_in_File(char *str) {

    FILE *fp;
    int line_num = 1;
    int find_result = 0;
    char temp[1024];
    if((fp = fopen("/Users/S/Documents/Learning/C/text.txt","r")) == NULL) {
        return(1);
    }
    while(fgets(temp, 1024, fp) != NULL)
    {
        if((strstr(temp, str)) != NULL)
        {
            find_result++;
            printf("A match found on line: %d at position: \n", line_num);
        }
        line_num++;
    }

    if(find_result == 0) {
        printf("\nSorry, couldn't find a match.\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char word;
```

You have declared a `char` variable , but in order to input  word you need a `char` array . Right now `word` can store only a single character.

Declare a sufficient enough `char` array -

```
char word[50];
scanf("%49s", word);
Search_in_File(word);            // no need to pass address
```

### EDIT-

And for your problem with getting position , you can make use of function `strtok` instead of `strstr` -

```
int position;
char *token;
while(fgets(temp, 1024, fp) != NULL)
{
    position =0;                      //set position to 0 in each iteration
    token=strtok(temp," ");           // search for space
    while(token!=NULL){
        position++;                   // as words are tokenized count spaces
        if(strcmp(token,str)==0){     //check for your word 
        find_result++;                       
        printf("A match found on line: %d at position: %d\n", line_num,position);  
      }      
     token=strtok(NULL," ");
    }
    line_num++;
}
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question; post as a comment not an answer.

Comment: I a'm not so good at C, but my 'char word' works good as well checked with one letter, if I'll put word like Steve, It will not match letter S :)

Comment: @Bestinthe I have updated the code , to give you position of word in line as well , please take a look .

Comment: @Clifford Before edit problem was not listed , but Thanks !! . And I have updated answer with the accurate solution .

Comment: The `strtok` delimiters should include all punctuation characters to work for all text so it will for example find `"hello"` in `"hello, world"`.  Suggest the set defined for `ispunct()` and `isspace()`, i.e. `" \t\n\v\f\r!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_``{|}~"`.  `strtok()` modifies the input string, which is often undesirable; in which case use `strcspn()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

The function `strstr()` returns a pointer to the occurrence of the word in the line.  Pointer arithmetic can be used to determine the position index:

```
    char* found_at = strstr( temp, str ) ;

    if( found_at != NULL)
    {
        int column = found_at - temp + 1 ;  // Plus 1 if left is considered column 1.
        find_result++;
        printf( "A match found on line: %d at position: %d\n", line_num, column );
    }
```

However while that will find the location of the found string, it does not have any sense of what constitutes a "word".  For example, it will find "man" in "mankind" for example.